# How do I rename the field names using pdflib?

Tags: pdf-lib.js

The names for the pdf fields currently are hard to know where each field is on the form and what's what so I wanted to either change the name of some of the fields that don't make sense or make the field names show up on the form so I know where to enter the data.

I've tried the following code but at field.setText I'm getting an error saying TypeError: fields.setText is not a function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcJQa.png)